# Original "default" background color for Preview windows?

Tags: preview, color

I am used to viewing and reading documents on Preview in the usual gray background color.

However, I recently changed the color to black (I was trying dark mode). And when I try to reset the background color (in the Preview preferences), it just stays black. So I am unable to return to the original gray color.

I've settled for now by picking a grayish color that looks similar to the original.
However, I'd very much like to have the original color back.

---

I was wondering if anyone knows what the "exact" original color is? For example, if anyone knows its RGB values, or its name in the "crayon section" of the settings color palette, this would be very helpful. Any help is much appreciated.

(For reference, I'm using Mac OS Monterey.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital Colour Meter says it's 236, 236, 236 in P3 or sRGB, 235, 235, 235, in Native [this was measured on a fully-calibrated display].

[image]