# Which exact color space is "RGB" in MacOS Finder's "Get Info"?

Tags: macos, finder, color

In MacOS Finder, if I *Right Click > Get Info* on an image – in this case a .PNG file – I see that it says `Color Space: RGB`.

- When Finder says "RGB", which exact color space specification do they mean?
- Is there any way I can tell exactly which color space specification this is?

---

NB 1: My ultimate objective is to find what is the exact color space specification of a .PNG image, and the proximate objective is to understand what exactly Finder means by "RGB".

NB 2: The file is from GIMP, so I think it might be an sRGB color space specification.

Comment: Curious when I do the same on a random PNG on my Mac (12.15.1), right below the color space (RGB) is "Color Profile." You could also open it in Preview and *then* get info on the file. That shows the color profile as well.

Comment: @SteveChambers Interesting, I don't have the "Color Profile" section in Finder for this file. In Preview, Inspector (CMD + I) says "Colour model: RGB", and "ColorSync profile: -" (empty).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Original "default" background color for Preview windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445631/original-default-background-color-for-preview-windows)

Comment: @SolarMike No, how is that pertinent to the question?

Comment: Try it in Preview and/or any other graphic tool you have available, it may be that the file was written without that info... but not knowing how the color space of a graphic file is declared I am unsure.

Comment: Suspect: 1) The Spotlight index and hence Finder does not distinguish colour Model, colour Space and colour Profile. 2) Finder says colour Space when it should say colour Model. 3) Finder/Spotlight are rubbery using colour Profile for what may be colour Profile or colour Space. 4) Do as @SteveChambers says and use Preview or Image Manager to get these details - if they are included in the image metadata.

Comment: @PAN In Preview you found "Colour model: RGB", and "ColorSync profile: -". Take that as true 1) Colour Model is RGB (in contrast to CMYK), 2) The image metadata does not specify a Profile or Space.

Comment: @Gilby That the image uses an RGB color space is without question. But there are many RGB color space specifications, so the question is which one, e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_spaces#RGB_color_space_specifications. In other words, if Apple recognizes it to be "RGB", which one do they know it to be?

Comment: @PAN The image says it is RGB colour model, but says nothing about colour space used when creating it. So neither Apple or macOS can know. Why do you need to know? How was it created? Can you put it (without conversion of any sort)  somewhere we can retrieve  and have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Finder knows only the broadest term - RGB. If there is an embedded profile, that will be used by any graphics app when opening the file.
Without a profile it will open in Photoshop etc as 'untagged RGB' which is to all intents & purposes assumed to be sRGB.

PNG files cannot contain CMYK images, only Greyscale, Indexed & TrueColor,  so at least that confusion is eliminated, but Finder cannot tell the difference between, say 'standard' RGB & Indexed colour, only between colour & greyscale.

Left to right - truecolor, indexed & greyscale. [Note the first two also have an embedded profile - my screen profile in this case, as the original is a screenshot - greyscale discards the profile]
[image]