# Unable to change window background color in Preview

Tags: preview, color

I am unable to change the window background color in macOS Preview (macOS Monterey Version 12.6.3)

It used to work but now it does not.  The window background color is stuck on black.  When I click on the "color well" it remains black and no color palette appears. [image]

Clicking on the "Reset" button has no effect.  I have tried exiting and restarting to Preview to no avail.  With other applications such as Apple Mail, changing colors is no problem.

I have searched the web for a solution but have not found this Preview problem addressed anywhere.  The only related problem I found is:

[Original "default" background color for Preview windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445631/original-default-background-color-for-preview-windows)

and there is no solutions given as to how to restore the color changing ablilty.